# Python - reference of objects in filtered list

Tags: python, reference, pass-by-reference

I have this `Hero` object in python

```
class Hero:
    def __init__(self, json_def, player_index):
        self._alive = True
        ... # other attributes
```

Then, I have list of `Hero` object, i.e.

```
Heroes = [HeroObj1, HeroObj2, HeroObj3, HeroObj4]
```

What I would like to do is filter the list and get the object reference, instead of the copies of the object. I know that I can do filtering like below.

```
filtered_list = [x for x in Heroes if x.alive]
```

However, this approach will result in copying the filtered objects to `filtered_list`. I would like to do reference so I could modify the initial list (`Heroes`) when I modified this filtered version/`filtered_list` (for example, only modifying the hero that is alive).

Is there any solution to achieve what I am looking for?

Any help would be appreciated! Cheers!

Comment: A typo: use `==` in your `if` to compare equality. `=` is simply an assignment.

Comment: for that matter, you wouldn't even need the == there, just `if x.alive`.

Comment: No, `[x for x in Heroes if x.alive]` creates a new list with references to the original objects. The objects are not copied. You could test that by doing `filter_list[0]._alive = "this is a test"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I misunderstand your question but the items in `filtered_list` are already references to the same objects held in `Heroes`. No copy of the objects have been made.

Modifications to the objects in `filtered_list` will also be visible if accessing the objects in `heroes` because they refer to the same objects.

```
>>> h = Hero()
>>> l1 = [h]
>>> l2 = [x for x in l1 if x._alive]
>>> l1[0] is l2[0]    # are they same object?
True
>>> l2[0]._active = False
>>> l1[0]._active
False
>>> l1[0] is l2[0]    # are they still same object?
True
```

They are the same object, hence the list is storing references to the objects, not the objects themselves, and no copy of the object is made by the list comprehension.